# firefox add-on sdk ToggleButton badgeColor displayed default red color

Tags: firefox, sdk, togglebutton, add-on, badge

when I resized the firefox window to just not display my add-on's toggleButton, then resized the firefox window to display my add-on's toggleButton. The badgeColor was displayed with default color(red).
How should I do and solve this problem? And is this the firefox's bug?

```
var {ToggleButton} = require("sdk/ui/button/toggle");
var button = ToggleButton({
    id:"aaaa",
    label:"aaaa",
    icon:{
      "16":"./aaaa-16.png",
      "32":"./aaaa-32.png",
      "64":"./aaaa-64.png",
    },
    onChange:changed,
    badge:"0",
    badgeColor:"#A9A9A9",
});

function changed(state) {
    if (button.badge == "1") {
        // code
        button.badge = "0";
    } else {
        button.badge = "1";
    }
    if (state.checked) {
        // code
        button.badgeColor = "#20B2AA";
    }
    else {
        button.badgeColor = "#A9A9A9";
    }
}
```

Comment: when I clicked the button the badgeColor displayed right.